# MySQL format issue

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have a MySQL query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`StartTime`, '+0:00', `timeZone`),'%b %d, %Y %h:%i %p') as start, 
       DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`endTime`, '+0:00', `timeZone`),'%b %d, %Y %h:%i %p') as end
```

which is giving output as

```
start = Nov 09, 2015 06:40 PM
end = Nov 09, 2015 07:10 PM
```

But I want the output in following format: `Nov 09, 2015 06:40 PM EST` instead of `Nov 09, 2015 06:40 PM`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the time zone already, you can just insert it into the second DATE_FORMAT() argument like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`StartTime`, '+0:00', `timeZone`),CONCAT'%b %d, %Y %h:%i %p ', timeZone)) as start, 
  DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`endTime`, '+0:00', `timeZone`), CONCAT('%b %d, %Y %h:%i %p ', timeZone)) as end
 FROM appointments
 WHERE CounselorID = 225 AND AvaliableStatus = '0' AND counselorsStatus = 0 AND Type = 2
```